Why is my exception getting printed twice?
The following code looks good to me, but when I use e0 with my except ValueError it prints twice, please help my slow brain
my inputs are 20.5 and 5
try:
    user_num = int(input())
    div_num = int(input())
    print(user_num / div_num)
except ValueError as e0:
    print('Input Exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10:', e0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Zero Division Exception: integer division or modulo by zero')

Output
Input Exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20.5'

Tried to remove e0, print my entire statement without e0, perfectly prints, but I cannot put the e0 otherwise it just prints the output  twice for some reason.

It's printing twice because you told it to print twice.  Your first exception handler prints the string "Input Exception: invalid literal for int() with base 10", and it also prints e0 which is basically a copy of that string.

e0 already has all the information you need.  You don't need the extra string before it.

By running the following code, it is easy to understand the problem:
>>> int("20.5")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20.5'

the raised exception's message is the exact message you want to print. So you can just print the e0 without leading string.
I prefer this:
try:
    user_num = int(input())
    div_num = int(input())
    print(user_num / div_num)
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError) as e:
    print(e)


e0 is not the string you tried to convert. e0 is the exception object. Printing that prints the exception's message, and the exception's message is "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20.5'".
"invalid literal for int() with base 10:" shows up twice in the output because you're printing it manually, and also printing an exception message with that text in it.

Thank you for your explanation, opens my eyes

the raised error (e0) includes "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20.5'"
a fix would be-
try:
    user_num = int(input())
    div_num = int(input())
    print(user_num / div_num)
except ValueError as e0:
    print(e0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Zero Division Exception: integer division or modulo by zero')

